# Video encode from sequence of images from java android

Tags: java, android, image, video-encoding, android-image

I would like to encode video from sequence of images with java only in my current android project. I mean without any use of external tools such as NDK.
Also is there any availability of java libraries for encoding video from sequence of images ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a pure java library called JCodec ( http://jcodec.org ). It contains a primitive yet working H.264 ( AVC ) encoder and a fully functioning MP4 ( ISO BMF ) muxer.
Here's a **CORRECTED** code sample that uses low-level API:

```
public void imageToMP4(BufferedImage bi) {
    // A transform to convert RGB to YUV colorspace
    RgbToYuv420 transform = new RgbToYuv420(0, 0);

    // A JCodec native picture that would hold source image in YUV colorspace
    Picture toEncode = Picture.create(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), ColorSpace.YUV420);

    // Perform conversion
    transform.transform(AWTUtil.fromBufferedImage(bi), yuv);

    // Create MP4 muxer
    MP4Muxer muxer = new MP4Muxer(sink, Brand.MP4);

    // Add a video track
    CompressedTrack outTrack = muxer.addTrackForCompressed(TrackType.VIDEO, 25);

    // Create H.264 encoder
    H264Encoder encoder = new H264Encoder(rc);

    // Allocate a buffer that would hold an encoded frame
    ByteBuffer _out = ByteBuffer.allocate(ine.getWidth() * ine.getHeight() * 6);

    // Allocate storage for SPS/PPS, they need to be stored separately in a special place of MP4 file
    List<ByteBuffer> spsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
    List<ByteBuffer> ppsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();

    // Encode image into H.264 frame, the result is stored in '_out' buffer
    ByteBuffer result = encoder.encodeFrame(_out, toEncode);

    // Based on the frame above form correct MP4 packet
    H264Utils.encodeMOVPacket(result, spsList, ppsList);

    // Add packet to video track
    outTrack.addFrame(new MP4Packet(result, 0, 25, 1, 0, true, null, 0, 0));

    // Push saved SPS/PPS to a special storage in MP4
    outTrack.addSampleEntry(H264Utils.createMOVSampleEntry(spsList, ppsList));

    // Write MP4 header and finalize recording
    muxer.writeHeader();

}
```

You can download JCodec library from a project web site or via Maven, for this add the below snippet to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcodec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcodec</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**[UPDATE 1]** Android users can use something like below to convert Android Bitmap object to JCodec native format:

```
public static Picture fromBitmap(Bitmap src) {
    Picture dst = Picture.create((int)src.getWidth(), (int)src.getHeight(), RGB);
    fromBitmap(src, dst);
    return dst;
}

public static void fromBitmap(Bitmap src, Picture dst) {
    int[] dstData = dst.getPlaneData(0);
    int[] packed = new int[src.getWidth() * src.getHeight()];

    src.getPixels(packed, 0, src.getWidth(), 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight());

    for (int i = 0, srcOff = 0, dstOff = 0; i < src.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < src.getWidth(); j++, srcOff++, dstOff += 3) {
            int rgb = packed[srcOff];
            dstData[dstOff]     = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;
            dstData[dstOff + 1] = (rgb >> 8) & 0xff;
            dstData[dstOff + 2] = rgb & 0xff;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will give a try then

Comment: Here is a little problem, how do i port import java.awt.image.BufferedImage; in android.   Android SDK doesnt support **awt**.  Thanks

Comment: See the **[UPDATE 1]** above.

Comment: You have `for (int i = 0, srcOff = 0, dstOff = 0; i < src.getHeight(); i++)` in your code, but dstOff is unused ;)

Comment: My edit isn't reviewed yet, but `Picture.create((int)src.getWidth(), (int)src.getHeight(), RGB);` should be `ColorSpace.RGB` I think ;) Also the int-casts aren't necessary.

Comment: For neatness I'd suggest incrementing the `srcOff` and `dstOff` in the body of the `for` loop instead. For example, `int rgb = packed[srcOff++]` and each of the `dstData` lines would become `dstData[dstOff++]` instead.

Comment: If anyone decides to go the jcoded way then there is a android version now and a BuildUtil class that contains the fromBitmap function.

Comment: @Raanan Any android tutorials on how to use jcodec on android? More specifically creating video out of images. Thanks!

Comment: @ZiadHalabi Sorry, I don't think I can help more then Google in this case. :(